# I want to version my database data, not the table structure of the database?

Tags: version-control, flyway

I want to version my database data, not the table structure of the database?

Is flyway OK? Or other methods？

Answer (score 0):

If by versioning your data you mean periodically running SQL scripts to manipulate the data en masse, or just maintaining static reference data, and keeping track of the scripts that have been run, then yes.

If you mean maintaining all past versions of an entity (corresponding to a set of rows) as your application evolves it, then no, that's not what Flyway is designed for.